# How to drop temp table in try catch block with transaction SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server

Hello i have the following query with a transaction in a try catch block and i rollback transaction on the catch block if fails. Problem is that I am creating a temporary table and i don't know how to handle it with a transaction. So how can I safely get rid of temporary table in this situation? I tried to add it on catch block but i'm not sure if this is a good practice

```
ALTER PROCEDURE GetDataForNewListaAbastecimento
    @UAP NVARCHAR(20),
    @ColaboradorId INT
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @TransactionName nvarchar(20) = 'GetDataForNewListaAbastecimento'
    DECLARE @Status INT
    DECLARE @CurrentWeekDay INT
    SET DATEFIRST 1
    SET @CurrentWeekDay = DATEPART (WEEKDAY, GETDATE()) - 1

    CREATE TABLE #tempTable
    (
        Id INT PRIMARY KEY,
        Referencia NVARCHAR(15),
        UAP NVARCHAR(20),
        ConsumoWeek01 FLOAT,
        ConsumoWeek02 FLOAT,
        Stock INT,
        QtdPecasPorCaixa INT    
        UNIQUE (Id)
    )


    BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRAN @TransactionName  

        DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
        SELECT @SQL = 'INSERT INTO #tempTable
        SELECT
            Id,
            Referencia,     
            UAP,
            ConsumoWeek01 AS ConsumoWeek01, 
            ConsumoWeek02, 
            CASE 
                WHEN Stock IS NULL THEN 0
            ELSE    
                Stock
            END AS Stock,
            QtdPecasPorCaixa
        FROM OPENQUERY(MACPAC, 
        ''WITH maxFornecedorByDate AS
         (
            SELECT
                YDA3REP.A3ARCD,
                YDA3REP.A3D5CD,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY YDA3REP.A3D5CD ORDER BY YDA3REP.A3A3DT DESC) AS Number
            FROM
                AUTO.YSACHAPOR.YDA3REP YDA3REP
         )  

        SELECT 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY A.RH6001 ASC) AS Id,
            A.RH6001 as Referencia, 
            A.RH6002 as UAP, 
            A.RH6030 as ConsumoWeek01, 
            A.RH6031 as ConsumoWeek02,
            IC130M.LLBLT1 as Stock,
            M.AUQCON AS QtdPecasPorCaixa
        FROM AUTO.D805DATPOR.TRP060H AS A
        LEFT JOIN AUTO.D805DATPOR.IC130M IC130M 
        ON A.RH6001 = IC130M.LLPPN AND
             IC130M.LLSTLC =
                 CASE A.RH6002
                      WHEN ''''UAP1'''' THEN ''''M1''''
                      WHEN ''''UAP2'''' THEN ''''M2''''
                      WHEN ''''UAP3'''' THEN ''''M3''''
                      WHEN ''''UAP4'''' THEN ''''M4''''
                      WHEN ''''UAP5'''' THEN ''''M5''''
                      WHEN ''''UAP6'''' THEN ''''M6''''
                      WHEN ''''UAPP'''' THEN ''''PROTOS''''
                      WHEN ''''EXT'''' THEN ''''EXTR''''
                    END
        LEFT JOIN 
        (
            SELECT 
                YDAUREP.AUD5CD,
                YDAUREP.AUQCON
            FROM maxFornecedorByDate F
            join AUTO.YSACHAPOR.YDAUREP YDAUREP
            ON F.A3ARCD = YDAUREP.AUARCD
            AND F.A3D5CD = YDAUREP.AUD5CD
            WHERE F.Number = 1 AND YDAUREP.AUD5CD LIKE ''''M%''''
            AND YDAUREP.AUD5CD NOT LIKE ''''%P%''''
            AND YDAUREP.AUA0NB > 1 
            AND YDAUREP.AUG6ST= ''''O''''
        ) M 
        ON M.AUD5CD = A.RH6001      
        WHERE A.RH6001 Not Like ''''FS%''''
        AND A.RH6030 <> 0
        AND A.RH6002 = ''''' + @UAP + ''''' '')'        
        EXEC sp_executesql @SQL

        INSERT INTO hListasAbastecimento (UAP,DataCriacao,ColaboradorId) VALUES (@UAP,GETDATE(),@ColaboradorId)

        INSERT INTO 
            hReferenciasAbastecimento 
            (
                Referencia,
                QtdAbastecimento,
                QtdCaixas,
                QtdPecasPorCaixa,
                ListaAbastecimentoId
            )   
        SELECT 
            C.Id,
            C.Referencia,
            ( T.ConsumoWeek01 / ( ( P.NumDias - @CurrentWeekDay ) * P.NumPAB )) * P.AlcanceAbastecimento AS QtdAbastecimento,
            T.QtdPecasPorCaixa,
            CASE
                WHEN ((T.ConsumoWeek01 / ( ( P.NumDias - @CurrentWeekDay ) * P.NumPAB )) * P.AlcanceAbastecimento) / NULLIF(T.QtdPecasPorCaixa,0) IS NULL THEN NULL
            ELSE
                CAST( CEILING(((T.ConsumoWeek01 / ( ( P.NumDias - @CurrentWeekDay ) * P.NumPAB )) * P.AlcanceAbastecimento) / T.QtdPecasPorCaixa )  AS INT)
            END AS QtdCaixas,
            SCOPE_IDENTITY()
        FROM 
            #tempTable T
        INNER JOIN hParametros P
        ON P.Referencia = T.Referencia 
        AND P.UAP = @UAP
        INNER JOIN hConsumos C
        ON C.Referencia = P.Referencia  
        AND C.UAP = @UAP
        WHERE T.Stock < ( T.ConsumoWeek01 / ( ( P.NumDias - @CurrentWeekDay ) * P.NumPAB )) * P.QtdMin
        ORDER BY QtdAbastecimento DESC

        COMMIT TRANSACTION @TransactionName 

        DROP TABLE #tempTable

        -- Success, Lista de abastecimento foi criada sem errors --
        SELECT @Status = 200
        RETURN @Status

    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        ROLLBACK TRAN @TransactionName
        DROP TABLE #tempTable
        SELECT
            ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber,
            ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState,
            ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity,
            ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure,
            ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine,
            ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;

            -- Erro, Nao foi possivel criar lista de abastecimento, verificar dynamic query -- 
            SELECT @Status = 400
        RETURN @Status

    END CATCH

END
```

**EDIT**

I'm calling the SP from an Asp .NET Core application with Entity Framework Core

```
  await _context.Database
        .ExecuteSqlCommandAsync("EXEC @Status = GetDataForNewListaAbastecimento @UAP, @ColaboradorId", @params);
```

Comment: Why are you using `sp_executesql` to run that non-dynamic query, and why are you injecting a value into it? That query shouldn't be being executed as a "dynamic" statement, and it *should* be parametrised; otherwise it's open to injection (even an `nvarchar(20)` can suffer injection).

Comment: A temporary table will only persist for the duration of the connection that created it. Assuming that you're opening a connection to run the SP (such as from an application) SQL Server will gracefully `DROP` the temporary table anyway. How are you executing the SP?

Comment: Oh I see, I'm callling it using entity framework on an asp .net Core Application. Also, i have to execute sp_executeSql because it is the only way to pass parameters from SQL to a db 2 linked server, unless i'm missing something but this is how my coworkers have been doing

Comment: Ahh, that's an `OPENQUERY` (it's quite difficult to see when a literal sting); in that case, yes, "injection" is the only way, however, I do suggest making it safe still. `QUOTENAME` is great for that. I can't test, but I think you want `AND A.RH6002 = ''''' + @UAP + ''''' ''` to `AND A.RH6002 = N' + QUOTENAME(QUOTENAME(@UAP,N''''),N'''') + N'` (note I have added `N` too, as `@UAP` is an `nvarchar` and it was being injected be a `varchar`)

Comment: I tried this but gives me incorrect syntax near the @UAP keyword, ´AND A.RH6002 = N' + QUOTENAME(QUOTENAME(@UAP,N''''),N'''') + N' '')'  
  EXEC sp_executesql @SQL´

Comment: As i said, I couldn't test, @Jackal, but I suggest using `QUOTENAME`. Using `PRINT` or `SELECT` to inspect the value of `@SQL´ will help. [Why QUOTENAME is important](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/why-quotename-is-important)

Comment: ok what you wrote gives me on print  AND A.RH6002 = N'''UAP1''' '),  I tried remove 2 quotes from each and result is  AND A.RH6002 = N[[UAP1]]] ')

Comment: Blarg, this is why dynamic dynamic SQL is a pain XD. Try `N'N''' + QUOTENAME(QUOTENAME(@UAP,N''''),N'''') + N'''';` That should cover the bases now.

Comment: here is what i tried that looks closer to solution    AND A.RH6002 = N' + QUOTENAME(@UAP,N'''') + N' '')'    it pritns  
 AND A.RH6002 = N'UAP1' '), seems like the only problem now is the initial N', i'm not sure what does it do or is it reading it wrong?

Comment: so i read it's something about nvarchar, the @UAP is already a NVARCHAR btw

Comment: It means the literal string is a `nvarchar` @Jackal. You aren't passing `@UAP` to the `OPENQUERY`, you're **injecting** it's value. `'UAP1'` is not an `nvarchar`  (N'UAP1'` is), so if you are injecting an `nvarchar` you need to ensure you make the string literal you inject is declared as one. Notice what happens here if you omit the `N` for example: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=312200e4c305fa0b14e5e26959aac526). Despite that all the characters appear correct in the value `@SQL`, when it's executed they are completely different.

Comment: this worked AND A.RH6002 = '''  + QUOTENAME(@UAP,N'''') +  ''''')'  but not sure if it is required to have N'''' before and after each plus sign? Because the 1st N always appears on the query as text

Comment: If your parameter (`@UAP`) is going to have a unicode character, then the above won't work as you expect. And if it won't ever have a unicode character, then you should declare `@UAP` as a `varchar`, rather than an `nvarchar` (to avoid confusion).

Comment: Ah I see how it works AND A.RH6002 = N'''  + QUOTENAME(@UAP,N'''') +  N''' '')', it might have unicode yes, so this is the final result, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try add this:

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Results') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Results

(Replace Name your temp table #Result)